# How to access the component that contains a component in Swing

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way for a component to access the component that contains it? For example, if there is a JPanel named firstPanel and I've added a secondJPanel Jpanel to firstJpanel, can secondJPanel call firstPanel with something like myContainer.setBackground?

Comment: Just call `secondJPanel.getParent()` .

Comment: @Berger post that as an answer

Comment: @jhamon: it's a common duplicate